# Calling a method from a method in another class

Tags: ruby

It's a fairly well know one. Determining the rank of a poker hand. I created the following classes: `Card`:

```
class Card
  attr_accessor :suite, :rank, :value
  def initialize(suite, rank, value)
    @suite = suite
    @rank = rank
    @value = value
  end
  def to_s
    puts "#{@value}, #{@suite}, #{@rank}"
  end
end
```

`Deck`:

```
class Deck
  def initialize()
    @cardsInDeck = 52
    @deck = Array.new()
  end
  def add_card(card)
    @deck.push(card)
  end
  def deck_size
    @deck.length
  end
  def to_s
    @deck.each do |card|
      "#{card.rank}, #{card.suite}"
    end
  end
  def shuffle_cards
    @deck.shuffle!
  end
  def deal_cards
    #Here I create a new hand object, and when popping cards from the deck             
    # stack I insert the card into the hand. However, when I want to print 
    # the cards added to the hand I get the following error:
    #     : undefined method `each' for #<Hand:0x007fa51c02fd50> (NoMethodError)from   
    #       driver.rb:36:in `<main>'
    @hand = Hand.new
    for i in 0..51 do
      card = @deck.pop
      @cardsInDeck -= 1
      puts "#{card.value}, #{card.rank}, #{card.suite}"
      @hand.add_cards(card)
    end
    @hand.each do |index|
      "#{index.value}, #{index.rank}, #{index.suite}"
    end
    puts "Cards In Deck: #{@cardsInDeck}"
  end
end
```

`Hand`

```
require_relative 'deck'
require_relative 'card'

class Hand
  def initialize()
    @hand = Array.new()
  end
  def to_s
    count = 0
    @hand.each do |card|
      "#{card.value}, #{card.rank}, #{card.suite}"
      count += 1
    end
  end
  def add_cards(card)
    @hand.push(card)
  end
  def hand_size()
    @hand.length
  end
end
```

and Driver File:

```
require 'logger'
require_relative 'card'
require_relative 'deck'
require_relative 'hand'

suite = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
rank = ["Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
deck = Deck.new()
suite.each do |i|
  v = 1
  rank.each do |j|
    deck.add_card(Card.new(i, j, v))
    v += 1
  end
end
```

In the `Deck` class, the `deal_card` method, I do not understand why looping for an array causes a method error

```
@hand.each do |index|
  "#{index.value}, #{index.rank}, #{index.suite}"
end
puts "Cards In Deck: #{@cardsInDeck}"
```

Answer (score 0):

`@hand` is an instance of `Hand`, and there is no instance method `each` defined for `Hand`, so that is why `@hand.each` is generating an `undefined method` error.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. It is not clear to me how I would loop over the array in the deck class, defined in the hand class, so as to list all the cards that have been added to the hand in the deck class.

Comment: You would need to define an `each` method within `Hand` or establish `Hand` as a subclass of a class which provides such a method (e.g. `Array`).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. :-) If you feel this post didn't acceptably answer your question, feel free to leave your question open for additional responses. Otherwise, you might want to "accept" it.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not very direct on the error but could hopefully help you in this case.

1. You method `deal_cards` is where **Dependency Injection** can play its role. By the original design `Deck` has a hard dependency on `Hand` which is not good and harder to test. You need to change it like

   ```
   def deal_cards(hand=nil)
     @hand = hand || Hand.new
     # Others
   end
   ```

   By this you can accept instance outside of `Hand`, say `Foot` as long as somebody can play cards by feet!
   You can also unit testing this method without writing Hand class at all.
2. Better to unit test the class instead of manual checking, then you can inject any instance you like into this method during testing.